# Search for filename containing a word

Tags: file, cakephp-2.0, directory

I want to create a search function that searches through a directory and returns all the filenames containing the search terms (either one or some or all the terms).

I am using CakePHP's `find` that is part of the built in `Folder Utility`.

Below is an extract of my code:

```
$terms = explode(' ',$this->params['url']['term']);
$dir = new Folder(APP . 'docs' . DS . 'qms' . DS . 'standardforms');
foreach($terms as $term) {
    $files[] = $dir->find(/*what goes here*/,true);
}
```

I know I'm adding an array to an array, but it's fine as I want to calculate relevancy later and sort by it.

Can someone please explain what should be inserted as the first argument in the `find`? Or is there a better/easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is everything you need to know:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html

Comment: Gee thank you. I did seriously not know that there is online documentation for CakePHP. I swear I always thought that when you used CakePHP that you are on your own in the wilderness and you need to sniff out how it works all by yourself. Life. Changed. Mind answering the question. Or do you want to post more links?

Comment: Realy?

$files[] = $dir->find( '.*' . preg_quote($term) . '.*',true);

Comment: Thank you. I suck at regular expressions. Trust me, I've read that page 100 times.